# Why does my y axis keep showing the wrong values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this table:

```
structure(list(Species = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor"), Variables = c("PetalLength", 
"PetalLength", "PetalLength", "PetalLength", "PetalLength", "PetalLength", 
"PetalLength", "PetalLength", "PetalWidth", "PetalWidth", "PetalWidth", 
"PetalWidth", "PetalWidth", "PetalWidth", "PetalWidth", "PetalWidth", 
"SepalLength", "SepalLength", "SepalLength", "SepalLength", "SepalLength", 
"SepalLength", "SepalLength", "SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "SepalWidth", 
"SepalWidth", "SepalWidth", "SepalWidth", "SepalWidth", "SepalWidth", 
"SepalWidth"), Values = c(4.7, 4.5, 4.9, 4.7, 4.4, 4.8, 4.5, 
4.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.8, 1.6, 1.5, 7, 6.4, 6.9, 6.3, 
6.7, 5.9, 6, 6.7, 3.2, 3.2, 3.1, 3.3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.4, 3.1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Even if I try to plot the most basic barplot to ever exist, i.e.:

```
grafico <- ggplot (data = tabela, aes (x = Variables, y = Values)) +
geom_bar (stat = "identity") +
windows (); grafico
```

This happens:

[image]

Why does the y axis keep showing values from 0 to 60 if the values are decimals that range from 0 to 10???

Comment: Because, as documented, `By default, multiple bars occupying the same x position will be stacked atop one another`.

Comment: Can you describe the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you're stacking your bars - you have multiple values per each x axis value.

So, you can do a few things, but in the end, to show "the right values", you have to only have one value per x-axis group (unless you're also colour-coding by another variable).

You can see your invididual points by colour-coding by id.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)

tabela %>% 
   group_by(Species, Variables) %>% 
   mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
   ggplot(aes (x = Variables, y = Values, fill= as.factor(ID))) +
   geom_bar (stat = "identity")
```

and now dodged, instead of stacked

```
tabela %>% 
   group_by(Species, Variables) %>% 
   mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
   ggplot(aes (x = Variables, y = Values, fill= as.factor(ID))) +
   geom_bar (stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```